# How to refer to something from a certain country?

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

I am beginning to learn japanese all over again (its been over 10 years) and I have started taking classes.

My teacher spoke of 3 suffix to describe people, language and item from a certain region

> Nihon-go = japanese languange
>
> Nihon-jin = japanese person

The third was how to describe an item, but he said he would explain what the suffix was later.

My curiosity has gotten the best of me, can someone tell me what the suffix is for describing an item from japan?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any *suffixes* for that off the top of my head. I would say 日本の(item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. If you generally want to say that something is from another country you can say countryのwhatever-the-thing-is. From there we can go into even greater specificity and say where something was manufactured (country製{せい}のthing), produced (country産{さん})のthing), or any number of other details, but it's really a case by case basis. There are also many words that denote the style or origin of things (和風{わふう} comes to mind), but these aren't quite as general and probably require that you have a sense of nuance when using them.

tl;dr countryのthing is the simplest way to say what you're talking about, but there do exist suffixes that will add a higher degree of nuance.